# Using haddock with Capistrano

Tags: ruby, rubygems, capistrano

First of all.. I'm new to Ruby and Capistrano.

I have a deployment task where I need to come up with a random password, so I found Haddock, which does the trick for me.

https://github.com/stephencelis/haddock

I installed the gem, and made a sample script just to make sure the gem was working fine. The script is as follows..

```
require "rubygems"
require "haddock"
include Haddock


newpass = Password.generate

print newpass
```

This does what I expected, it prints a random string.

Now when I include the two require and include lines in my Capfile, I get the following error.

**/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:122:in `method_missing': undefined method`include' for # (NoMethodError)
from Capfile:21:in `load'**

It looks like Ruby is failing on a simple "include" now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capistrano doesn't run `deploy.rb` like any other Ruby script, it will `load` (or eval, not sure which off the top of my head) it inside a specific context to make it's DSL work properly. This means that a few things you'd expect to work will not. One of those things is, apparently `include`. Try removing it and change `Password.generate` to `Haddock::Password.generate`.

Comment: Another thing that will not work is putting more Capistrano config directives in a separate file and `require`-ing it from your `deploy.rb`. You must use `load` (this is also the reason why `Capfile` uses `load` and not `require` to load `config/deploy.rb`).